# How to list number of open file descriptors by process for all processes on Unix?

Tags: lsof

I need to list every process and how many file descriptors are open for that process so that I can figure which processes are keeping way too many open files. No, I don't need the number of open files for just one process as other questions have asked. I need to know the number for every running process, preferably sorted in descending order.

lsof doesn't seem like it can do this. Is there any other utility or something that can accomplish this?

Comment: Which Unix variant or variants?  Does it have a `/proc` file system? (Mac OS X doesn't; Linux and Solaris do.)  Do you need to work on multiple platforms?

Comment: Including or not `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`?

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something like:

```
sudo lsof -FKc |
  awk '
   function process() {
     if (pid || tid) {
       print n, \
             tid ? tid " (thread of " pid ": " pname")" : pid, \
             name
       n = tid = 0
     }
   }
   {value = substr($0, 2)}
   /^p/ {
     process()
     pid = value
     next
   }
   /^K/ {
     tid = value
     next
   }
   /^c/ {
      name = value
      if (!tid)
        pname = value
      next
   }
   /^f/ {n++}
   END {process()}' | sort -rn
```

For number of open *files*, and replace `/^f/` with `/^f[0-9]/` for number of open *file descriptors*.

Answer (score 2):

This will work at least with Solaris and Linux and probably with most other OSes supporting a `/proc` file system:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /proc
echo "  count  pid"
ls -d [1-9]*/fd/* 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\/fd.*$//' | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Use `-rg` instead of `-rn` under Linux or other OSes using GNU `sort`.

Comment: In reverse order then use `sort -nr`

Comment: @fduff indeed, the OP asked for a descending order. Thanks.